# Webview Video doesn't stop on Backpress - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview, webchromeclient

In my android application I want to open a webpage in a `Webview`. A webpage which i want to open also contains video. To achieve this functionality, I used `WebChromeClient` in my application. The problem is that, `OnBackPressed()` of this activity, some videos don't get stopped and they keep playing in background, though my Webview activity is finished. I don't know why this happens. I tried various codes, but couldn't solve this problem. Some videos stop automatically, but some keeps on playing in background. How to solve this issue ?

Please help me to solve this problem.

Here is my code :

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("Test HTML5:-", "onDestroy Called...");
        mWebView.stopLoading();
        // mWebView.clearCache(true);
        // mWebView.clearHistory();
        // mWebView.pauseTimers();
        abc.removeView(mWebView);
        mWebView.removeAllViews();
        mWebView.destroy();
        mWebView = null;
        finish();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

write this code on onPause()

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.e("Test HTML5:-", "onDestroy Called...");
        mWebView.reload();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Comment: Should i remove it from `onBackPressed()` ?

Comment: I tried this code but its not working. I don't know why its not working. I guess activity is creating any background media/audio object for playing this file and i'll have to destroy that object. Is it possible ?

Comment: And also dont override onDestroy() method

Answer (score 1):

Use to onBackPressed

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        mWebView.stopLoading();
        mWebView.removeAllViews();
        mWebView.destroy();
        mWebView = null;
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```